# Boost для Dev-C++

Tags: c++, boost

Использую `IDE Dev-C++`, встроенный компилятор: `TDM GCC 4.7.1 64-bit release`
Скачал `boost_1_41_0`. Следуя инструкции ввожу в консоль

> set PATH=D:\Soft\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin;%PATH% //Мой путь к папке MinGW64
>   cd /d d:\boost_1_41_0 //Сюда распаковал архив с boost
>   bootstrap.bat gcc

После чего вижу следующие строки:

> Building Boost.Jam build engine
>   "cl" не является внутренней или внешней
>   командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Как это исправить, и установить boost?

Comment: `cl` - это компилятор Visual C++, у вас же явно GCC...

Comment: @Harry Ну я же нигде не использовал команду cl, я писал bootstrap.bat gcc . А выбивает ошибку про cl. Что же делать?

Comment: Значит, нужно отыскать в командном файле упоминания cl и заменить повсеместно на gcc и проверить правильность путей к исполнимым файлам.